# Unable to autoload constant ProfileProjectsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error while visiting /project/my/tasks in Rails 5 as Unable to autoload constant **ProfileProjectsController**, expected **/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/profile_projects_controller.rb** to define it

controller code

```
class Project::ProfileProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if current_user
      @projects = Project.where(user_id: current_user.id)
      render 'profile_projects/index'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the controller into the `controllers/project` folder.  The module name `Project` becomes a folder in the `controllers` directory.